# antd: Customize Theme for Input and Form using ConfigProvider not working in React web

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have theme setup that looks like this;

```js
<ConfigProvider
      theme={{
        components: {
          Form: {
            colorPrimary: '#cb1d4d'//red
          },
          Input: {
            colorPrimary: '#cb1d4d'//red
          },
          /*Radio: {
            colorPrimary: '#cb1d4d',
            colorPrimaryBorderHover: '#cb1d4d',
            colorPrimaryHover: '#cb1d4d',
            colorPrimaryActive: '#cb1d4d',
            colorPrimaryTextHover: '#cb1d4d'
          },*/
          Button: {
            // colorPrimary: '#038A96'
            colorPrimary: '#cb1d4d'
          }
        },
        token: {
          // colorPrimary: '#038A96'
          colorPrimary: '#3d91ff'//blue
        }
      }}
    >
//.... The rest of the app

</ConfigProvider>
```

Both the `Radio` and `Button` themes take effect in the whole application except the `Input` and `Form` which sticks to blue.

When I comment out the `token` block, both `Input` and `Form` still remains as blue.

I'd really appreciate a solution for this.

**This is Antd Version:** `"^5.3.2"`